# Can I have Celery reenqueue a task?

Tags: python, celery

I'm using a Celery task queue to process web requests asynchronously. If I wanted to prevent workers from processing the same kind of task too often, is it possible for a worker to reenqueue a task? It's certainly possible to have a worker sleep on a task, but I don't want to tie up workers sleeping on tasks. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

My answer almost certainly lies in ETA/Countdown options:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown
[How can I defer the execution of Celery tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006151/how-can-i-defer-the-execution-of-celery-tasks)

I hadn't considered putting the wait logic on the task-generator side. I'll play with this a bit.